# Comparing a column of string date-times with Now()

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I know `if date value()<Now()` and `timevalue()<Now` but what about both date and time?

Column B has due dates. I need it to say if the date-time listed in Column B is less than now (past the due date), blablabla

So how do i represent the value of the date-time cell so I can compare it with B?

This works for JUST the date:

`=datevalue(B:B)<Now()`

but it needs to be date-time value and I can't find a function for that!

Answer (score 0):

Add `DateValue` and `TimeValue` together and compare the result to `Npw`.

```
=(datevalue(B2)+timevalue(B2))<now()
```

Dates and times are just numbers. A date is *1* for every day past Dec 31, 1899. Today happens to be 42,113. Time is a decimal portion of a day so today at noon was 42,113.5 and today at 06:00 PM will be 42,113.75. `DateValue` can only resolve the date (integer) portion of a string datetime and `TimeValue` can only resolve the time (decimal) portion but once you have two actual numerical values, you can simply add them together to reform the correct datetime.